# Understanding Git Cherry Pick conflict

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick, git-merge-conflict

We recently switched from SVN to GIT, and I'm having some trouble converting our previous workflow. Mostly everything works, but today I got a weird cherry-pick conflict.

I'm able to resolve the conflict, but I would like to know where this came from, because to my understanding there shouldn't be a conflict in this situation.

**Setup**

In our repository we have a `master` branch on which we develop. Four times a year we release a new version. We branch of of `master` into `Release-x` and this gets shipped after testing.

We have several release-versions in production at the same time. If a bug is found, this has to be fixed on all (supported) release branches. So a single release branch using tags to identify the different releases isn't a valid workflow.

So we currently have these branches: `master`, `Release-15Q1`, `Release-15Q2` and `Release-15Q3`

Say for example we found a typo causing a bug in `master`, we would fix it and then `cherry-pick` it onto `Release-15Q1`, `Release-15Q2` and `Release-15Q3`

**So, now onto the conflict I'm facing:**

The file `properties.dat` was changed in `master`, after branching `Release-15Q3`

*Properties.dat* (`Release-15Q3`)

```
serverip=1.1.1.1
serverport=11
name=MyApp
```

*Properties.dat* (`master`)

```
serverip=2.2.2.2
serverport=22
name=BetterName
```

Development went on... all good. 
Then we noticed a bug where we needed to add an extra property to the file to disable the bug.

*Properties.dat* (`master`)

```
  serverip=2.2.2.2
  serverport=22
  name=BetterName
+ allowBug=false
```

This fix-commit also needs to be applied to the three other branches. So I go to each branch and use the cherry-pick command.

This is giving me conflicts on the first three lines, but I don't really understand why.

I was under the assumption that with cherry-picking you would only *replay* that specific commit, so only add the *allowBug=false* line at the right spot. It shouldn't matter if other changes were made, right?, because I'm not merging the branches?

Why is this giving a conflict? Shouldn't these other changes be ignored?

Answer (score 1):

When cherry-pick is issued, first git computes the  differences with its parent. This results in a diff-file (a.k.a. patch). This patch not only contains what has changed (i.e., `+ allowBug=false)` but also the surrounding context of the changed line(s). Hence, the patch file would look something like:

```
@@ -1,7 +1,7
serverip=2.2.2.2 
serverport=22  
name=BetterName
+ allowBug=false
```

Once the patch is computed, git will try to apply it into your release branch. The *context* lines of the patch files (those without +/-) tells git *where* to apply the `+ allowBug=false`. Since the surrounding context cannot be found in the Properties.dat on release branches, the patch cannot be applied and git raises a conflict.

A bit late, but hope it helps :)

**EDIT**: you might have a look at [git cherry-pick: how consider only lines modified by the commit (i.e., not the surrounding context)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871750/git-cherry-pick-how-consider-only-lines-modified-by-the-commit-i-e-not-the-s)

Comment: PS: once you resolve the conflict, if   you are concerned about git remembering how you resolved such conflict, you can enable git rerere:

git config --global rerere.enabled true